# How are constructors with default parameters called in inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: c++, inheritance, default-constructor

I have this simple code:

```
class C0
{
        public:
                C0(std::string i) : i_(i) {}

        private:
                std::string i_;
};

class C1 : public virtual C0
{
        public:
                constexpr static auto const e{"e"};

                C1(std::string i = e) : C0(i) {}
};

class C2 : public virtual C1
{
        public:
                C2(std::string k) : k_(k) {}

        private:
                std::string k_;
};
```

Compiled as: `[clang++|g++] -std=c++17 example.cpp`

I get the following error:

With g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0:

```
example.cpp: In constructor ‘C2::C2(std::__cxx11::string)’:
example.cpp:23:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘C0::C0()’
                 C2(std::string k) : k_(k) {}
                                         ^
example.cpp:6:17: note: candidate: C0::C0(std::__cxx11::string)
                 C0(std::string i) : i_(i) {}
                 ^~
example.cpp:6:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
example.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: C0::C0(const C0&)
 class C0
       ^~
example.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
example.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: C0::C0(C0&&)
example.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

With clang++ version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2:

```
example.cpp:23:17: error: constructor for 'C2' must explicitly initialize the base class 'C0' which does not have a default constructor
                C2(std::string k) : k_(k) {}
                ^
example.cpp:3:7: note: 'C0' declared here
class C0
      ^
```

Why does the compiler complain about missing default constructor in class `C0` when the default constructor of class `C1` explicitly calls `C0` constructor passing the argument?

When I define a default constructor in `C0`, the call to `C0(i)` from `C1` does not happen. So the member variable `C0::i_` is not initialised. Shouldn't there be a call to `C0(i)` rather than the default constructor of `C0` when `C2` is instantiated?

Comment: It's because of the virtual inheritance. Read more about virtual inheritance in your favourite C++ book. (clang tells you what you need to do, but not why.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most derived class is the one that is responsible for constructing the virtual bases. To fix this, add `: C0(k)` to `C2`.

Comment: Please don't answer obvious dupes.  It makes the site harder to maintain.